# Firestore query array/rules not working resources.viewers

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to get the "read" Rules working from an array as per this blog https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

```
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  db.collection("_users").where("viewers", "array-contains", myUID)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
      });
    });
```

---

Same in AngularFirestore

```
this.itemsCollection_users = this._afDB.collection("_users", ref => ref.where("viewers", "array-contains", myUID)))
```

---

```
The DB 
/_users/EGsht477klOKW0YeYsryo0j8AkY2/sometext = "hello",
/_users/EGsht477klOKW0YeYsryo0j8AkY2/viewers [
  0: hKeDFsC6wOQZGz0rP7SnJ7Vo5O73,
  1: Y8xbH2avmCWmm1EBK7wappM2qE03
]
```

---

The DB Rules
service cloud.firestore {

```
  match /databases/{database}/documents {   
    match /_users/{userId} {

        allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.viewers;    

    }
}
}
```

---

So user EGsht477klOKW0YeYsryo0j8AkY2 should be accessable (read) from any users listed in "viewers"

The warning I get is...

```
ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `resource` variable in your security rules point to a [`Resource` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource). To get at its data you need to use `resource.data`, so:

```
 allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.viewers;
```